# Invalid hook call when extracting react hooks in nested forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use formik `<FieldArray />` where I can use the `push` arrayHelper to fill in the array data. In the [example](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray), they are creating the form straightaway from the button. However I want to extract it to use `useCallback`

Here's the initiative that I did

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { useField, FieldArray } from "formik";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { FormikTextField, formStyles } from "./Utils";

function WitnessChild({ remove, push }) {
  const classes = formStyles();
  const [field] = useField("witnesses");

  const handleAdd = useCallback(
    () =>
      push({
        FirstName: "",
        LastName: "",
        AddressStreet: "",
        AddressSuburb: "",
        AddressPostcode: "",
        Mobile: ""
      }),
    [field.value]
  );
  return (
    <>
      {field.value.length > 0 &&
        field.value.map((witness, index) => (
          <div>
            <div className={`${classes.margin} row`}>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                component="label"
                className={`${classes.instructions}`}
                onClick={handleAdd}
              >
                Add New
              </Button>
            </div>
            <div className={`${classes.margin} row`}>
              <div className="col-6">
                <FormikTextField
                  className={`${classes.instructions}`}
                  id={`witnesses.${index}.FirstName`}
                  name={`witnesses.${index}.FirstName`}
                  label="First Name"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-6">
                <FormikTextField
                  className={`${classes.instructions}`}
                  id="witnessLastName"
                  name="witnessLastName"
                  label="Last Name"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={`${classes.margin} row`}>
              <div className="col-6">
                <FormikTextField
                  className={`${classes.instructions}`}
                  id="witnessAddressStreet"
                  name="witnessAddressStreet"
                  label="Street"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-6">
                <FormikTextField
                  className={`${classes.instructions}`}
                  id="witnessAddressSuburb"
                  name="witnessAddressSuburb"
                  label="Suburb"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={`${classes.margin} row`}>
              <div className="col-6">
                <FormikTextField
                  className={`${classes.instructions}`}
                  id="witnessAddressPostcode"
                  name="witnessAddressPostcode"
                  label="Postcode"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-6">
                <FormikTextField
                  className={`${classes.instructions}`}
                  id="witnessMobile"
                  name="witnessMobile"
                  label="Mobile"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </>
  );
}
export default function WitnessDetails() {
  return <FieldArray name="witnesses" render={WitnessChild} />;
}
```

I'm not sure why it returns:

> ×
>   Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>   See link for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

I can actually remove this error by creating the handleAdd func inside the button `() => {}`, however I don't think that's a good practice because it will be initiated every time. Can anyone tell me what is the best practice in extracting hooks like this?

Thanks

Comment: `const classes = formStyles();` What do you do in `formStyles()`? Try moving that line after `const handleAdd = useCallback(...)`

Comment: That's a hook from material-ui styles, created with `makeStyles from "@material-ui/styles";`

Comment: If it's a hook, its name should be started with `use`. https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api

Comment: Shoot you're right! Thanks for noticing another bug